# Josephus Problem with cyclic iterator

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

Given the Josephus Problem.

> Josephus Problem
>
> N people (numbered 1 to N) are standing in a circle. Person 1 kills Person 2 with a sword and gives it to Person 3. Person 3 kills Person 4 and gives the sword to Person 5. This process is repeated until only one person is alive.
>
> Task:
>   (Medium) Given the number of people N, write a program to find the number of the person that stays alive at the end.
>   (Hard) Show each step of the process.
>
> (The description from Sololearn application)"

This is my code. The `forEachRemaining` method solution is correct? I have to do something with this inherited method, but it has no meaning.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

class CyclicIterator implements Iterator {

private final List list;
private Iterator iterator;

public CyclicIterator(List list) {
    this.list = list;
    initIterator(list);
}

private void initIterator(List list) {
    this.iterator = list.iterator();
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return !list.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public Object next() {
    if (!this.iterator.hasNext())
        initIterator(list);
    return this.iterator.next();
}

@Override
public void remove() {
    this.iterator.remove();
}

@Override
public void forEachRemaining(Consumer action) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This method has no meaning in CyclicIterator class!");
}
}

public class JosephusProblem {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    execution(0);
    execution(1);
    execution(2);
    execution(4);
    execution(6);
}

private static void execution(int members) {
    if (members < 1) {
        System.out.println("The parameter (members) has to be bigger than 0!");
        return;
    }
    if (members == 1) {
        System.out.println("There is olny one person, so he is the survivor. Peaceful version! :)");
        return;
    }
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList();
    for (int index = 0; index < members; index++)
        list.add(index + 1);
    Iterator<Integer> it = new CyclicIterator(list);
    System.out.println("For " + members + " members: ");
    while (members-- > 1) {
        System.out.print(it.next() + " kills " + it.next() + ", ");
        it.remove();
    }
    System.out.println("\n The survivor: " + it.next());
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is off: there should be a level also after `class`, not only in methods:

```
class CyclicIterator {
    // Class members here
}
```

Always try to instantiate to an interface, not an implementation:
This:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList();
```

Should be:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

Note there the diamond operator `<>` to actually get a genericized list. Without it, you should have got a compiler warning about using raw lists. The diamond operator is shorthand for giving the generic type to the implementation: `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

I would also prefer using System.out.format to just smashing strings together in a println call: `System.out.format("For members %s:%n");`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `forEachRemaining` states that the behavior is equivalent to

```
while (hasNext())
    action.accept(next());
```

so why not just put that there?

Comment: I think that would be an infinite loop. The `hasNext()` is always true if the list is not empty.

Comment: Of course the next line has a next() call in it … `action.accept(next())`.